# Android Facebook SDK --null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

How do I get user's first name,last name,dob,gender and email from facebook..my app is crashes everytime..
below is the error..

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getFirstName()' on a null object reference
```

--

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); // Facebook SDK initialization
        ButterKnife.bind(this); // Butterknife initialization
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        currentProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        updateUserProfile();
    }

    private void updateUserProfile() {
        if(currentProfile.getFirstName() != null) {
            tvFirstName.setText(currentProfile.getFirstName());
        }

        if(currentProfile.getLastName() != null) {
            tvLastName.setText(currentProfile.getLastName());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that currentProfile is null. You should do a null check and then get the current profile according to the Facebook SDK flow.

`Profile.getCurrentProfile()` Will return the current profile if there is one, but there won't be one until the user is logged in and has accepted your app and there usually won't be one kept between launches of your app, so you need to do the authentication flow each time.

In case you don't know `onResume` is called just before we show the UI and let the user interact with it. The facebook popup can't have appeared to let the user interact at this point, and once it does you need to make sure any asynchronous interactions are completed before you try and use their results. That's what all the callbacks are for.